# How to show sale icon in category list pages in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to show sale icon with saved amount percentage in magento, so far I am successful doing this. But the problem I am facing is
the sale icon show at all pages whether the product has special price or not. The sale icon must only show when there is special price. I am using the following code in list.phtml. I am not programer. I appreciate your help to correct these code so that sale icon only appear when there is a special price. Thanks in advance

```
<?php $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
$regularprice = $_product->getPrice();
// Get the Special Price FROM date
$specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
// Get the Special Price TO date
$specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
// Get Current date
$today = time(); if ($specialprice)if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime

($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate))$discount = 100 

- round(($specialprice / $regularprice)*100); {?><span class="onsaleicon"><span class="onsaletext"> <?php echo 

$discount .'% OFF' ;?></span></span> <?php } ?></a>`
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

here

$stodate =  special price to date

$sfromdate =  special price from date

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$special=$_product['special_price'];
$price=$_product['price'];
$stodate=$_product['special_to_date'];
$sfromdate=$_product['special_from_date'];

    if (!$special == null) {

        if (isset($sfromdate) and $date >= $sfromdate) {
        {
            if(isset ($stodate)){
                if($date <= $stodate ){
                     ?>
            <div class="onsaleicon">
                <span class="discounttext">
                    <?php
                    echo round(100 - ($special / $price) * 100) . "%";
                    ?>              
                </span>

            </div>              
            <?php

                }

            }else{
                 ?>
            <div class=""onsaleicon">
                <span class="discounttext">
                    <?php
                    echo round(100 - ($special / $price) * 100) . "%";
                    ?>              
                </span>

            </div>              
            <?php
            }

        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but used the Marius solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.
Add this at the top of `catalog/product/list.phtml`:

```
$_taxHelper  = $this->helper('tax');
```

And use this code to determine if a product has a special price. It will work if the special price is set manually or if it's determined by a catalog price rule.

```
<?php $_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());?>
<?php $_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice()) ?>
<?php $_regularPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), $_simplePricesTax) ?>
<?php $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()) ?>
<?php if ($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
   YOUR SALE LABEL HERE
<?php endif;?>
```